# Best way to upgrade the Spyder2 IDE that was packaged with Python(xy)

Tags: python, spyder, pythonxy

I recently purchased a high resolution laptop. My Spyder IDE now has small icons and is nearly unusable. I found a solution on Stack Overflow however my version of the IDE doesn't have the functionality needed to fix the problem. I'm assuming I have an older version of Spyder (version 2.3.5.2). What is the best way to upgrade without causing problems with the rest of Python(xy)?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Such old Spyder versions don't have support for high resolution screens. Besides, I think PythonXY is unmaintained right now (last release was in 2015).

So you basically have two options: 1. Download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/), which comes with Spyder and the most important Python scientific libraries, and it's also is what we recommend; or 2. Download Python 3 from its [website](https://www.python.org/) and then use `pip` to install Spyder. However, option 2. is for experts because a lot of things can go wrong with it.

Comment: I used Spyder because I didn't want to become an IDE expert. It was just a nice interface. I also use Python(x,y) because it has packages that I use that Anaconda does not. I guess option 3 would be find another IDE.

Comment: If you want a clear cut answer to your question, that would be: there's no way to update Spyder in PythonXY and get its interface adapted to high resolution screens. I was being polite by offering you other options, but you can disregard them if you want.